# Make clang initializing an array by copy from constant when type has volatile copy-assignment operator

Tags: c++, clang, volatile

I have a class similar to

```
class A {
public:
    constexpr A(int v) : v(v) { /* logic */};
    A& operator=(const A&) = default;

    // This is error: the parameter for an explicitly-defaulted copy assignment operator may not be volatile
    // A& operator=(const volatile A&) = default;

    // This disables initializing A by memcopy from a global constant.
    A& operator=(const volatile A& a) {
        v = a.v;
        return *this;
    }

    int v;
};

void f() {
  // 1st requirement: Fast constant initialization of big arrays  
  A a[20] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19};

  // 2nd requirement: Allow assignment from volatile
  volatile A b(1);
  a[0] = b;
}
```

(https://godbolt.org/z/fz5raT1n8)
and I would like to
a) both allow the code in f() to compile, especially the assignment from a volatile object.
This is because there are already users of the class that do this, and it's hard to upgrade them.

b) and make the initialization of big arrays of A efficient. When I remove the volatile operator=, then clang creates a constant global and a memcpy (https://godbolt.org/z/37j1zesjY), but I didn't find a way how to achieve this while still having requirement (a). It seems that clang only performs this initialization when the class is trivially copyable.

I tried defaulting the `A& operator=(const volatile A& a)` but that is not allowed by clang. I checked the clang source code (`AggExprEmitter::EmitArrayInit` in `CGExprrAgg.cpp`) to find that it checks whether the type is trivially copyable before doing this optimization.

Is there a way how I can write my code to achieve this?
If no, would it be a conforming implementation to change clang to perform the
the initialization via a constant global even when the class is not trivially copyable as long as the copy constructor that would be used is trivial?

Thanks!

Comment: Why was volatile added in the first place? Are you on an embedded platform and do you expect memory mapped IO there? Or are you assuming it is because you think volatile makes things threadsafe?

Comment: Volatile has been there for a long time, and now users depend on it. It likely doesn't make sense to have volatile here, but at the same time, I don't want to break the existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bug in Clang; while *the programmer* may only expect `memcpy` to be well-defined when used on trivially copyable types, the *compiler* is permitted to replace a series of simple stores to adjacent memory locations with a `memcpy` call when it can determine that the result will be the same, regardless of whether the type is trivially copyable or not. Based on my brief experiments on Godbolt, GCC is able to perform the optimization without any issues. I recommend filing a bug report with Clang.

A workaround is to make the second assignment operator a template that is constrained to only accept `const volatile A&`. Its templated nature prevents it from being considered a copy-assignment operator, which means `A` is still trivially copyable.

```
template <class Other,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<Other, volatile A>::value>* = nullptr>
A& operator=(const Other& a) {
    v = a.v;
    return *this;
}
```

You might also want to make it accept any `Other` that's the `volatile` version of any class *derived* from `A`, not just `A` itself. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

(There are still more cases where this template will not accept the same arguments as the corresponding non-template function, and in some cases there might be nothing that the class author can do about it. However, I expect that the number of call sites that have this issue will be low, so perhaps those can just be fixed.)